# PHPMyAdmin on Docker with Laravel Sail POST Content-Length exceeds the limit

Tags: laravel, docker, phpmyadmin, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel environment running on Docker via Sail on Mac OS X Big Sur. I added a phpmyadmin to my docker-compose.yml file and it's all working, but when I try to import my data to the database, I get:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 68109047 bytes exceeds the limit of 2097152 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

I published the docker config files to my Laravel project and restarted docker. Here's my docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    myadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        links:
            - "mysql:db"
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

and in docker/8.1/php.ini

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS
```

But still no luck. I also tried running this command and then at the prompt:

```
sail php -a
phpinfo();
```

Which revealed this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

But there is no php folder in my /etc folder. I also noticed this in my docker config at docker/8.1/Dockerfile

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container
```

But again, there is no /etc/php folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is not correct.

```
UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100000
```

specifies an limit of 100000 Bytes! So that is 97,66kB.

Comment: That's correct - I had to use: UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100000000

Answer (score 12):

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin you need to specify in your docker-compose.yml file the environment variable UPLOAD_LIMIT to your desired limit. Eg.

```
myadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100000000
    links:
        - "mysql:db"
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    networks:
        - sail
```

so as to have an upload limit of 100.000.000 bytes.

Comment: As noted by karakai, I had to use: UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100000000
to allow 100MB uploads (the MySQL I was uploading was 64MB)